# APNS implementation in C#

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement push notification services in windows by following [this link](https://github.com/arashnorouzi/Moon-APNS/blob/master/Application/MoonApns/PushNotification.cs).

Starting from MAC I am able to create SSL certificate(cer) and key (p12) files. I also installed these two files on Windows server by following [this link](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/04/).

Now the issue is, when I execute .Net code, I am able to send a message but in the response I'm getting an exception. When it goes into the `ReadResponse` it gives the error `Input string was not in a correct format` on this line :

```
payLoadIndex = ((Convert.ToInt16(payLoadId)) - 1000);
```

It happens because `payLoadId` is blank. It says that "Notification successfully sent to APNS server for Device Token" but I get no notifications. I assume if this `ReadResponse` worked I would be able to know what the error was.

One thing I noted in some post is that after following the above procedure they create the PKCS12 format file for the notifications to work, using OpenSSL.

If this is required, which key should I use, "p12" or "PKCS12"?

Comment: The code in the link you provided has `payLoadIndex = ((int.Parse(payLoadId)) - 1000)` instead of the line you have in your question. If you reach that line, what values do you get for command & status? command should always be 8. status will tell you the type of the error.

Comment: p12 and pkcs12 are the same thing.

Comment: @Eran payLoadId is always "0/0/0/0"

Comment: What are the values of command and status? And do you set the PayloadId of your NotificationPayload?

Comment: @Eran oh I just resolve the issue, this was related to adding certificate in Microsoft Management Console (MMC). Will post the detailed solution